# Congruences to the same value

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $S \equiv n \bmod p_i$, for every $i=\overline{1,k}$, where $p_i$ is a prime factor of $m$ (i.e $p_1p_2\cdots p_k=m$). Anyway, $n$ has the same value for each $p_i$ in our equation.

Is it true that $m$ $|$ $n$ ?

Comment: What *is* true is that $\,m\mid S-n\,$ if the primes $\,p_i\,$ are distinct (else replace $\,m\,$ by $\,{\rm lcm}\{p_i\}),\,$ i.e. $\, S\equiv n\pmod{m}\,$ for $\,m = {\rm lcm}\{p_i\}\,$ for *any* integers $\,p_i.\,$  Is that what you intended? $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true: Take $m=2\cdot 3$, $n=1$, and $S=7$.